# How to show image path in image view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-imageview, android-image

Dears

I am Making a movie app that have two activities first activity have gridview that

shows grid of movie posters and whenever you click on any poster it will take you

to the other activity which is suppose to show the poster of the movie you clicked on

and detail text.

what is my problem?

when the second activity starts the movie detail is displayed but the poster is

not showing, how to display an image using an image path like this

"6bCplVkhowCjTHXWv49UjRPn0eK.jpg"? below the related code:

First Activity:

```
  gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,   long l) {

            String movieDetailText = "ID:" + movieId[i] + " \n" + "Title:\n"  + movieTitle[i] + "\n"
                    + "Over View:\n" + movieOverview[i] + "\n" + "Release   Date:\n" +
                    movieReleaseDate[i] + "\n" + "Rating:\n" +  movieVoteAverage[i];
            String movieDetailImage = moviePosterPath[i];

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,movieDetailText);
            intent.putExtra("image_path", movieDetailImage);
            startActivity(intent);




        }
       });
```

Second Activity:

```
   Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            String movieDetail = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
                    .setText(movieDetail);
            String posterImage = intent.getStringExtra("image_path");
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(posterImage);
                    ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_image))
                    .setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: It this image stored in the device or it is a URL (stored in a server)?

Comment: I download it in the first activity from themoviedb and want to display it in the second activity

Comment: Take a look to libraries, as Image Loader or Picasso, they do all the job for you. You can download and display the image. I will do a better answer below

Comment: I am using Picasso in the first activity and tried to use it in the second activity it did not work.

Comment: And when I debuged the second activity I noticed that the poster string path is stored in the string variable posterImage

Comment: Please check your "posterImage" what you are getting in this variable and is image available on this path or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following to fix my issue:

```
            String imagePath = intent.getStringExtra("image_path");
            String posterImage = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + imagePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). You just need the **URL** and the **ImageView** reference in the second activity:

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap to callback
imageLoader.loadImage(imageUri, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        // Do whatever you want with Bitmap
    }
});
```

Add the library in your gradle:

```
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
```

See how to use the library [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).